# How to work out if the mouse is over a ToolStripButton when overriding OnRenderButtonBackground

Tags: .net, vb.net, rendering

I am overriding the `OnRenderButtonBackground` method in order to use custom colouring, but I want to know if the mouse is currently over the button.

I tried to get the parent control (the toolstrip) and the parent form and add all the co-ordinates together but this is not correct:

```
Private Class MyRenderer
    Inherits ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
    Protected Overrides Sub OnRenderButtonBackground(e As ToolStripItemRenderEventArgs)
        Dim btn = TryCast(e.Item, ToolStripButton)
        If Not btn Is Nothing AndAlso btn.Checked Then

            Dim bounds As New Rectangle(Point.Empty, e.Item.Size)
            Dim ts As ToolStrip = e.Item.GetCurrentParent
            Dim f As Form = CType(e.Item.GetCurrentParent.GetContainerControl, Form)
            Dim btnRect As New Rectangle(f.Location.X + ts.Location.X + e.Item.Bounds.X, f.Location.Y + ts.Location.Y + e.Item.Bounds.Y, e.Item.Bounds.Width, e.Item.Bounds.Height)

            If btnRect.Contains(MousePosition) Then
                'doesn't reach this path...
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.Blue), bounds)
            Else
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.Red), bounds)
            End If
        Else
            MyBase.OnRenderButtonBackground(e)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'm sure there must be a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Try to read the bounds of the control. Then u can compare these values with the current location of the mouse

Comment: @Tomtom - the bounds of the control give the location of the `toolstripbutton` *within* the `toolstrip` whereas the `MousePosition` give the screen co-oridinates relative the top left corner of the primary screen so they are not compatible

Comment: You can call the method PointToScreen on both locations and then u can compare it.

Comment: @Tomtom - PointToScreen only works on a control doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to use the `MousePosition` for this.

Try this instead:

```
If e.Item.Selected Then
  e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, bounds)
Else
  e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, bounds)
End If
```

Note: You aren't disposing your Brushes.  Try disposing them or use the SystemBrushes as exampled.

Comment: Yes this works but I don't really understand why the selected property works in this way?

Comment: @MattWilko Yeah, it's not the best naming convention.  Think of it as "Highlighted" or "MouseOver".